# How pass multiple filters for a where clause in .NET EF core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

As below I am passing a lambda expression to the repository class to filter users based on their ids.

```
_repository.GetStudentUsers(studentUser => studentUser.StudentId.Equals(srequest.Id));
```

This is what `GetAStudentUsers` method in the repository class looks like.

```
public IQueryable<StudentUser> GetAStudentUsers(Expression<Func<StudentUser, bool>>? filter = null)
        {
            if (filter is not null)
            {
                return dbContext.StudentUsers
                .AsQueryable()
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(filter)
                .OrderBy(t => t.StudentName);
            }
            else
            {
                return dbContext.StudentUsers
                    .AsQueryable()
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .OrderBy(t => t.StudentName);
            }
        }
```

My problem is how can I modify this to pass multiple filters to the method in the repository class. When I add multiple lambda expressions it is showing cannot use `&&` operator to operands of type bool.

Comment: Don't create your own repositories if you're using EF Core. EF already implements the repository pattern itself. The `DbContext` is the unit of work and each `DbSet` is a repository.

Comment: Regardless, you can call `Where` as many times as you like. Just create the query first then call `Where` in a loop for each filter.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I modify this method that can have multiple filters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the `Where` method several times. It builds up the query, effectively `AND`ing the filters. Until you actually enumerate the `IQueryable` endpoint, it won't build an actual SQL and query the database.

Like this:

```
public IQueryable<StudentUser> GetAStudentUsers(params Expression<Func<StudentUser, bool>>[] filters)
{
    // prepare a base query
    var query = dbContext.StudentUsers
            .AsQueryable()
            .AsNoTracking();

    // apply filters
    if (filters != null)
    {
        foreach (var filter in filters) query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    // finalize the query by ordering the results
    return query.OrderBy(t => t.StudentName);
}
```